# Is there an end= equivalent for inputs?

Tags: python-3.x, input

So as I'm sure you know there's a specific operator for print() functions called end.

```
#as an example
print('BOB', end='-')
#would output
BOB-
```

So is there something like this for inputs? For example, if I wanted to have an input that would look something like this:

```
Input here
►
-------------------------------------------------------
```

And have the input at the ► and be inside the dashes using something like
`x = input('Input here\n►', end='-------')`
Would there be some equivalent?

EDIT:
Just to be clear, everything will be printed at the same time. The input would just be on the line marked with the ►, and the ---- would be printed below it, but at the SAME time. This means that the input would be "enclosed" by the ---.

Also, there has been a comment about curses - can you please clarify on this?

Comment: You should consider using [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) for this sort of input and generally for "random access" text UIs.

Comment: To be clear: Do you want the `----` to be printed _before_ the input is entered, and/or in the same line as the input itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using basic console IO, once a line has been ended with a newline, it's gone and can't be edited. You can't move the cursor up to do print anything above that last line, only add on a new line below.

That means that without using a specialized "console graphics" library like `curses` (as [tobias_k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639625/tobias-k) suggests), you pretty much can't do what you're asking. You can mess around a little with the contents of the last line (overwriting text you've already written there), but you can't write to any line other than the last one.

To understand why console IO works this way, you should know that very early computers didn't have screens. Instead, their console output was directly printed out one line at a time on paper. While some line printers could print several characters on the same spot (to get effects line strikethrough or underline), you couldn't unprint anything once it was on the paper. Furthermore, the paper feed only worked in one direction. Once you had sent a newline character that told the printer to advance the paper, you couldn't go back to an old line again.

Answer (score 1):

Not *exactly* what you want, but if the `---` (or `___`) can also be on the same line, you could use an input prompt with `\r`:

```
input("__________\r> ")
```

This means: print 10 `_`, then go back `\r` to the beginning of the line, print `>`  overwriting the first two `_`, then capture the input, overwriting more `_`. This shows the input prompt `> ________`. After typing some chars: `> test____`. Captured input: `'test'`

For more complex input forms, you should consider using [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would solve your problem:

```
print(f">>> {input()} ------")
```

OR

```
print(f"{input(">>>")} ------")
```

F-strings are quite useful when it comes to printing text + variables.

Comment: Ok, I tried this: what happened was the input (using the second example) came up blank until I entered the input. Then it printed the rest of the >>s and --s. However, I wanted it to be printed at the SAME time, so the input might be 'enclosed' by the ---- if you know what I mean.